# How to replace a letter in a string?

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I'm trying to resolve the fibonacci's rabbits problem. Usually, this question implies that bunnies growth in 'n' months never dies. But now, dies at 'm' months.

I want to simulate this situation. So, I have created a dictionary with keys and values for every change. Something like:

```
kbunny = {'a': 'b', 'b':'ca', 'c':'a'}
```

Later, I want to search in a string called 'gbunny' every key, and replace that key with its value.

```
gbunny = 'a'
for key, val in zip(kbunny.keys(), kbunny.values()):
     for a, b in enumerate(gbunny):
          if b[a] is key:
               b[a] = b[a].replace(key, val)
```

But, I didn't know than strings are immutable in python.

What other options I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to re-think your approach. It is true that string is immutable, however you can employ some helper list to do the job.

Each time we start with gbunny, use the dictionary to get the corresponding values and store it into a list. convert this list to string, use that string value to refresh gbunny, then clear the helper list, then continue to next iteration.

sudo code:

```
kbunny = {'a': 'b', 'b':'ca', 'c':'a'}
gbunny = 'a'
# you can create helper list here or somewhere else, 
# the location depends on how you want to handle the 'empty helper list' process

# You want to set a max_interation number so the loop can exit 
while max_iterations: 
    # use the kbunny to map each character in gbunny to its corresponding string and store in helper list 
    # convert helper list to string using ''.join()
    # pass the new string value to gbunny 
    # reset helper list to empty
    # decrease max_iterations by one 
    # continue to next iteration
```

This sounds like an interesting problem and I don't want to just give you the solution. comment below if you had any issues.

Comment: Yeah! It's very interesting. It's part of the Rosalind Project for Bioinformatics training in python. But this problem has taked three days of my life and I want to complete it. Thanks.